# lastpass password strength - difference between upper and lower case

Tags: aes, lastpass

I understand www.lastpass.com uses AES256 algorithm as explained at : 
https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=1096

> AES utilizing 256-bit keys as well as PBKDF2:
>   https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/account-settings/general/password-iterations-pbkdf2/

lastpass provides a bar to indicate password strength. Using 'asdf1111' as a password gives a moderate password strength :

[image]

Same password but uppercase 'ASDF' provides a stronger password (indicated by green bar) :
[image]

Why is uppercase text password stronger than lowercase ? I assume it's related to the AES256 algorithm implementation ?

Comment: This password strength meter is probably an entirely proprietary solution and has nothing to do with PBKDF2's or AES' specifics. Since it's probably proprietary, this cannot be answered.

Comment: Uppercase letters are much rarer in normal text that lowercase letters, so their usage is probably encouraged more.